# how to use CollectionView with TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

Hi how can we connect a Collection View with Table View iOS 7+ for an iPhone app..

I wanna have a scroll view up top part of the screen, and on the remaining screen, I wanna have a TableView, essentially showing more info on whatever the users selected in CollectionView.

As I'm new to iOS, would be great if you can point me to any useful resources.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this but I usually do both in a single view controller.  Some will disagree with that approach.  However, it is simpler, and simple is good.

To do this you can create a blank VC and initialize your collection view and table view & add to the VC's view, and specify your VC as the delegate & data source.  Then, you implement the collection view & table view methods & delegate methods.  Once the CollectionView cell is selected, you can update the table view datasource (if an array) or run a predicate against your core data, whatever, followed by a reload on the table view to get the new details.

Just be sure to implement all the required methods for UICollectionView and UITableView which you will get from the Apple docs.  If you do that it should be straightforward.

And I have no idea what you got a downvote on the question.

Answer (score 0):

finally I managed to get this semi working..thanks RegularExpression!! ( obviously there's been a lot of learning along the way )..however, I've noticed..on Collection View, 'cellForItemAtIndexPath' is called twice..as as result..my table view always shows data for next cell..couldn't work out whats happening..This is my VC code..I couldn't workout what I'm doing wrong..do I need to look into using 2 containers on the main view and adding CollectionViewController and TableViewController..not sure thats any better approach..but before I go to that approach..would like to see if there is anyway I could fix what I have now..

```
- (void) setManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    _managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;

    [self performFetchForCV];

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[LineLayout alloc] init];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
}

-(void)performFetchForCV {

    if (!_fetchedResultsController) {
        NSFetchRequest *request= [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
        gymClassesRequest.predicate = nil;
        gymClassesRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                                                                            ascending:YES
                                                                             selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]];

        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&gymClassesError]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", gymClassesError, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (void)performFetchForTV:(NSPredicate *)predicate {

    if (!_fetchedResultsControllerForTV) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity2"];
        gymScheduleRequest.predicate = nil;
        gymScheduleRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"day" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]];

        _fetchedResultsControllerForTV = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"day" cacheName:nil];
    }

    [_fetchedResultsControllerForTV.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_fetchedResultsControllerForTV performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseCollectionViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    MyEntity *entity= [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.nameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.nameLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    cell.nameLabel.text = entity.name;

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name= %@", entity.name];
    [self performFetchForTV:predicate];

    return cell;
}
```